# count down in flutter( not depending on device time)

Tags: flutter, dart, countdown, stopwatch

I'm building a flutter app where I want to restrict some of the users for a week and also show them the remaining time in days and hours so when the apps get close the timer should never get stopped. and also the date and time should not depend on the device time (if they change device time it should not affect the countdown)

Comment: How do you plan on doing this restriction? Like, how will the user know they are restricted? Through some API you control I assume. Just have that API return the time remaining then, or the end datetime, along with the server's current datetime and calculate the difference

Comment: The users can challenge each other for a small match once a week. so if they played with one player then they will be restricted for a week